# Potential illegal fragment detected when using OrmLite SqlExpression with Mysql?

Tags: mysql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

When I try to execute the following line:

```
var vehicles = db.Select<VehicleResponse>(q => q.Select(
"SELECT make, model, year, color FROM Vehicles").Limit(skip: 0, rows: 10));
```

I get the error:

`Potential illegal fragment detected: SELECT make, model, year, color FROM Vehicles`

If I execute the following, I don't get the error:

```
 var vehicles = db.Select<VehicleResponse>(
 "SELECT make, model, year, color FROM Vehicles").ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should normally use the [Custom Sql API's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-sqlexpressions-with-custom-sql-apis) like `db.SqlList<T>` when executing Custom SQL.

If you want to use Custom SQL in a typed `SqlExpression` you should use the `Unsafe*` API's to by-pass any Custom SQL detection.

But for the `Select` API of an SqlExpression you should only be adding the "SELECT..." part of an SQL Statement, e.g:

```
var vehicles = db.Select<VehicleResponse>(q => q.From<Vehicle>().Select(
    "make, model, year, color").Limit(skip: 0, rows: 10));
```

Although in this case I wouldn't bother with specifying the column list and just let it select all matching columns, e.g:

```
var vehicles = db.Select<VehicleResponse>(q => 
    q.From<Vehicle>().Limit(skip: 0, rows: 10));
```

Comment: Hi mythz. Just want to say that I am new to OrmLite and it is great along with all the other service stack stuff. Your team has done a great job.  I am not sure what you mean by `custom SQL`.  Do you have  an example of what would be custom vs non-custom?  Thanks

Comment: @xaisoft By Custom SQL I just mean executing any Raw/partial SQL statements as opposed to using the typed API's.

Comment: I tried the unsafe option and it gave me the error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT make, model, year, color FROM \`Vehic' at line 1`.  Looks ike it didn't remove the backtick from the Tablename

Comment: So when you saw raw or partial, you mean if I am returning a dynamic object as opposed to a strongly-typed POCO, for example?

Comment: How would I apply the `skip` and `limit` to the `db.SqlList` function?

Comment: @xaisoft Yeah the issue is you should only add the "SELECT ..." part of the SQL in the `Select()` API. I've updated with modified examples. You normally wouldn't need to include `db.From<T>` which is implied with what you're selecting, but you do in this case since you're mapping the table into a different POCO, e.g. `VehicleResponse` instead of `Vehicle`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I tried all 3 examples you gave and it worked great.  My `POCO` is different from my table, but I just added a `DataAnnotation` to get that working.  The only issue I ran into was that From did not like `From<VehicleResponse>("Vehicles")`.  It complained about the generic parameter.  The table actually has 100 columns, so in this case, I prefer to specify the rows because `MySql` acts strange when you do `SELECT *`. But it is good to know it is there.  Between the 3 you showed me, is there a preference you have?  For example, if a POCO is large or small.

Comment: Ah, one last question, when doing Limit, is it good to Order on a column first?

Comment: @xaisoft I generally prefer the shorter more typed option :) When Selecting into a different POCO like this it should only select the matching columns so you shouldn't need to specify the columns individually. Except for `db.From<T>` which needs to be first to create the right typed instance, the rest of the API's should follow normal SQL ordering, so put `Limit()` last.

Comment: Is it possible to get the total count of the table at the same time with limit or do I have to run a separate query?

Comment: @xaisoft OrmLite API's are just a thin, typed layer over SQL where the generated SQL should be predictable, i.e. it doesn't perform any "magic" hidden queries. So as it's not possible to access the COUNT when using LIMIT in normal SQL, it's not possible in OrmLite either. So you would need to use a separate query, e.g. OrmLite' explicit `db.Count` API's.